# Mimic nav-collapse animation in bootstrap nav on dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

Using the standard Bootstrap 2 nav-collapse markup employs a nice transition on the height of the 'collapse' class when the navigation toggle appears under 979px. I'd like to apply that same transition to the 'dropdown' class at full and collapsed widths.

You can see the current effect here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ when you size the browser below 760px.

The effect I'm after is the transition when the main toggle button is clicked in the upper right corner. You'll notice that if you then click on the 'dropdown' link below it, there is no transition. I'd like them to match.

My markup is below. Again, this is using Bootstrap 2

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>

            <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
            <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="images/image.png" alt=""></a>

            <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Active page</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Toggle link</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>


              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```